# How to open the view pager for first time and not on the second time using shared preference?

Tags: android

I have created two activities First one is Tour.java and Second one is Home.java. Tour activity is for View pager and i  have created a view pager for my android application. I used shared preference. But if i open the application the view pager cannot be viewed, directly it goes to home page. The condition i gave for the view pager is if the user opens the application for the first time the view pager should be shown to the user and for the second time it shouldn't. But I am facing problem with this i can't able to view the view pager for the first time itself.
**Tour.java**

```
public class Tour extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ViewPager mpager;
    private int[] layouts = {R.layout.firstslide,R.layout.secondslide,R.layout.thirdslide,R.layout.fourthslide};
    private MpagerAdapter mpagerAdapter;
    private LinearLayout Dots_Layout;
    private ImageView[] dots;
    private Button bnnext,bnskip;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (new PreferenceManager(this).checkPreference())
        {
            login();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
        {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
        else
        {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }


        setContentView(R.layout.tour);

        mpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mpagerAdapter = new MpagerAdapter(layouts,this);
        mpager.setAdapter(mpagerAdapter);

        Dots_Layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dotslayout);

        bnnext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bnnext);
        bnskip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bnskip);
        bnnext.setOnClickListener(this);
        bnskip.setOnClickListener(this);

        createDots(0);

        mpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                createDots(position);

                if (position == layouts.length-1)
                {
                    bnnext.setText("Start");
                    bnskip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    bnnext.setText("Next");
                    bnskip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void createDots(int current_position)
    {
        if (Dots_Layout != null)
        {
             Dots_Layout.removeAllViews();
             dots = new ImageView[layouts.length];


             for(int i = 0; i<layouts.length; i++)
             {
                dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
                if (i==current_position)
                {
                    dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.active_dots));
                }
                else
                {
                    dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.default_dots));
                }

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(4,0,4,0);

                Dots_Layout.addView(dots[i],params);
             }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.bnnext:
                loadNextSlide();
                break;
            case R.id.bnskip:
                login();
                new PreferenceManager(this).writePreference();
                break;
        }

    }

    private void login()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GridHome.class));
        finish();
    }


    private void loadNextSlide()
    {
        int next_slide = mpager.getCurrentItem()+1;

        if (next_slide<layouts.length)
        {
            mpager.setCurrentItem(next_slide);
        }
        else
        {
            login();
            new PreferenceManager(this).writePreference();
        }

    }


}
```

**PreferenceManager.java**

```
public class PreferenceManager {

private Context context;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public PreferenceManager(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    getSharedPreference();
}

private void getSharedPreference()
{
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.my_preference),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void writePreference()
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(context.getString(R.string.my_preference_key),"INIT_OK");
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean checkPreference()
{
    boolean status = false;
    if (sharedPreferences.getString(context.getString(R.string.my_preference_key),"null").equals("null "))
    {
        status = false;
    }
     else
    {
        status = true;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the Boolean not string.

```
public void setIntroShown(boolean flag) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getEditor();
        editor.putBoolean("intro", flag);
        editor.commit();
    }   

 public boolean checkPreference() {
            initializeSharedPreference();
            return sharedpreferences.getBoolean("intro", false);
        }




private SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor() {
        initializeSharedPreference();
        return sharedpreferences.edit();
    }

     private void initializeSharedPreference() {
            if (sharedpreferences == null) {
                sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefTags.APP_PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

-First check which is your launcher activity is home.java is your launcher activity then you have to remove its from manifest file.

-Check before the preference before tour.java activity execute. if preference false then redirect to tour.java activity otherwise start home activity.

is there is confusion then let me know.

thanks.

**I don't know How to check the preference before tour.java execute?**

-simple you can check it on splash screen after check preference then redirect to either tour.java or home.java. clear?

Comment: <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Tour" />
        <activity android:name=".GridHome" />
        <activity android:name=".Login"></activity>
    </application>
I hope my manifest is correct. I don't know How to check the preference before tour.java execute?

Comment: Still same result @husen